# Can I import .obj files for use on the iPad

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ipad

Is it possible to create 3D models in other applications (e.g. Vue Esprit) and then export these models as .obj files for use in iPad applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [this](http://code.google.com/p/iphonewavefrontloader/) OBJ loader hosted at google code.

It was developed by Jeff Lamarche in a series of [blog](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/search/label/3D%20Models) posts.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any built in support for this, but you can use any C or C++ based OBJ loader to get the data into a usable format, and then render using your standard GL functions.

A good place to start is the [GLGravity](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/GLGravity/Introduction/Intro.html) sample, which has a 3D teapot that it draws, this doesn't have an OBJ loader though.